# How to prevent scrolling when adding new items into LazyList?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

When the top item is shown (eg loading)  on the screen and new items are added at the start of the list, then LazyColumn scrolls to the very top. What I am trying to achieve - replace the loading item with the last of the newly added items, so the user can smoothly scroll to the top. One of the important conditions - the list originally has to add items from top to bottom, thus the reverse layout does not fit.

It seems that behaviour is controlled by LazyListState.updateScrollPositionIfTheFirstItemWasMoved thus I tried to play with none or various keys for loading item but without success. [image]

```
  class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            ListScrollTestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    ListTest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ListTest(viewModel: ListViewModel = viewModel()) {

    Column {
        val grouped = viewModel.state.collectAsState(emptyMap()).value
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.weight(1f),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
        ) {
            item(key = "loading"){
                Label("loading")
            }
           grouped.keys.forEach { key ->

                stickyHeader(key = key) {
                    Header(name = key.toString(),Modifier.animateItemPlacement())
                }
                val list = grouped[key] ?: emptyList()
                items(list, key = { it }) {
                    Label(name = it,Modifier.animateItemPlacement())
                }
            }
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            viewModel.onClick()

        }) {
            Text("add more to top")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Header(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "$name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Composable
fun Label(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = " $name!",
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.LightGray),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}

class ListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val alphabet = ('A'..'Z').toList()
    var index = alphabet.lastIndex
    val data = MutableStateFlow(listOf<String>())
    var _state = data.map {
        it.groupBy { it[0] }
    }
    val state: Flow<Map<Char, List<String>>> = _state

    fun onClick() {
        val letter = alphabet[index].toString()
        val newItems = (0..19).map {
            letter + it.toString()
        }
        index--
        data.update { data -> newItems + data }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution. To manage scroll seems we have to provide the same key to the last of newly added items as we provided to the first item which was the loader item. Thus in `resolveItemKey` I am shifting all keys by one index.

Solution is yet partial as it introduces really weird animation for replaced items.

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ListTest(viewModel: ListViewModel = viewModel()) {

```
Column {
    val grouped = viewModel.state.collectAsState(emptyMap()).value
    LazyColumn(
        Modifier.weight(1f),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        grouped.keys.forEachIndexed { groupIndex, key ->
            val list = grouped[key] ?: emptyList()
            if (groupIndex == 0) {
                item(key = list.firstOrNull(), contentType = 0) {}

                item(key = "loader$key", contentType = 1) {
                        Log.e("mcheck", "loader ket ${list.firstOrNull()}")

                        Label("loading key: ${list.firstOrNull()}")
                    }
                
            }

            stickyHeader(key = key, contentType = 2) {
                Header(name = key.toString(), Modifier.animateItemPlacement())
            }
            itemsIndexed(
                list,
                key = { itemsIndex, item ->
                    resolveItemKey(
                        grouped,
                        key,
                        groupIndex,
                        itemsIndex
                    )
                },
                contentType = { itemsIndex, item -> 3 }) { itemsIndex, item ->

                val resolvedKey = resolveItemKey(
                    grouped,
                    key,
                    groupIndex,
                    itemsIndex
                )
                Label(name = item + " key:" + resolvedKey, Modifier.animateItemPlacement())
            }
        }
    }
    Button(onClick = {
        viewModel.onClick()

    }) {
        Text("add more to top")
    }
}
```

}

private fun resolveItemKey(
group: Map<String, List>,
groupKey: String,
groupIndex: Int,
itemIndex: Int
): String {
val keys = group.keys.toList()

```
return if (groupIndex == keys.lastIndex) {
    val list = group[groupKey] ?: emptyList()
    if (itemIndex < list.lastIndex) {
        list[itemIndex + 1]
    } else {
        "first"
    }

} else {
    val list = group[groupKey] ?: emptyList()
    val nextKey = keys[groupIndex + 1]
    val nextList = group[nextKey] ?: emptyList()
    if (itemIndex < list.lastIndex) {
        list[itemIndex + 1]
    } else {
        nextList.firstOrNull() ?: "error $groupIndex $itemIndex"
    }
}
```

}